# Declaring fixed-size NSData() object

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create fixed-size NSData object to possibly improve performance.

```
var data = NSData(bytes: [], length: 18)
```

In Swift playground I see the result

`<a074740f 01000000 00bf740f 01000000 babc>`

Is it correct? Shouldn't they all be 0?

Also, is it a good practice to instantiate a NSData object with fixed-size when I'm sure it's going be that long?

It's worth to say that I need to "empty" this object after each time it's used, I read that the best way to accoplish that is just to assign a new object

```
self.data = NSData()
```

What if I use here the first snippet of code with fixed-length? I'll get these random values instead of empty NSData with fixed size

EDIT:

To provide more details about what I am actually trying to achieve:

I read data from BLE, to synchronize them I use timer that reads the current value form variable and clears that variable value afterwards.

First of all, I'd like to declare fixed-size NSData variable, because i suppose it will hone the entire performance

Second, I'd like to clear variable value after being used

This is how I do it on String to see them printed in console, by default i want to store values as NSData and pass to another class

```
class DataSynchronizer
{
var timer:NSTimer
var tag1:NSData = NSData()
var tag2:NSData = NSData()
var gpsData:CLLocation?
var timeInterval:Double


init(frequency:Double)
{
    self.timer = NSTimer()
    self.timeInterval =  1 / frequency

}

func scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(){
    // Scheduling timer to Call the function **Countdown** with the interval of 1 seconds
    self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(self.timeInterval, target: self, selector: #selector(DataSynchronizer.syncValues), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func stopTimer()
{
    self.timer.invalidate()
}


@objc func syncValues()
{
    print(self.tag1)
    self.tag1 = NSData()
    print(self.tag2)
    self.tag2 = NSData()
    print("\n")
}
}
```

tag1 and tag2 values are modified from another class that handles BLE

```
    func peripheral(peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: NSError?) {
    if self.updateStarted == false{
    self.updateStarted = true
    }

    let firstTagIdentifier = self.tagsIds[0]

    if "\(peripheral.identifier)" == firstTagIdentifier
    {

        self.peripheralCounter = self.peripheralCounter + 1

        let date = NSDate()
        if characteristic.value?.length == 18
        {

            synchronizer.tag1 = characteristic.value! //synchronizer is a DataSynchronizer instance
        }
```

Comment: `NSData(bytes: [], length: 18)` is undefined behavior, it would read 18 bytes from an empty array. If you provide more information about how the data is filled and used then better answers about "good practice" are possible.

Comment: check my edit, hope this helps

Comment: Doesn't reading from BLE give you a (new) NSData object? Pre-assigning would make no sense then.

Comment: it does, but I'd prefer to omit having repeated values, so I decided to clear the variable until the new value from BLE is assigned. I have two tags and I want to synchronize them

Comment: Please show how self.data is filled from BLE.

Comment: see my edit please

Comment: I can see no NSData in your code, and no reading from BLE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122098/discussion-between-dcdc-and-martin-r).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var data = NSData(bytes: [], length: 18)
```

causes undefined behavior: It reads 18 bytes from an empty array.

```
let data = NSMutableData(capacity: 18)!
```

would create an (empty) data object with the capacity to hold 18 bytes,
and

```
let data = NSMutableData()
data.length = 18
```

would create a data object with 18 zero bytes. You can empty the
contents with

```
data.length = 0
```

**But:**  With

```
synchronizer.tag1 = characteristic.value!
```

the value stored in `synchronizer.tag1` is *overwritten,*
which means that the previously assigned data object is released.
It does therefore not matter if you assigned a fixed-size data object before or not. It is also no performance improvement because you got the
`NSData` object from `characteristic.value`.

If you want to "clear" the data in the synchronizer class then define
the tags as optional variables:

```
var tag1: NSData?
var tag2: NSData?
```

Now you can assign data, and get rid of it by assigning `nil` again:

```
tag1 = nil
tag2 = nil
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The conclusion is that I shouldn't bother with trying to declare fixed-size. However, is clearing value by assigning new NSData() object resource-consuming?

Comment: @DCDC: It allocates an object, so there is a tiny (probably irrelevant) overhead. But optionals are the Swift way of defining a variable which has a value or not.

Comment: yes that's true but if I want to pass to to struct and read afterwards, I'd have to go into a lot of unwrapping and stuff. You know it's discouraging, but  if it is the only correct way of doing it, it's ok, I will do it using optionals;)

Comment: A fixed size NSData object is pointless if you haven't set the contents as well, because NSData is immutable - if you created an NSData object of 18 bytes, then you could never change the size (which may be Ok) but you also could not change the data.